# MySQL IF statement, record a value when this is down by n%

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I need some support regard a MySQL query.
I really don't know if possible to do that only via MySQL query, as I would like to skip a complex PHP function.

I have this query in a PHP script that update my database every 5 minutes (via CRON) from a parsed XML feed:

```
INSERT INTO $jackpot->gameId (gameId,gameName,amount,currency,date,hit,hit_date) VALUES (\"$jackpot->gameId\", \"$jackpot->gameName\" , \"$jackpot->amount\", \"$jackpot->currency\",CURRENT_DATE(),0,NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount=$jackpot->amount
```

Now, I would "enhance" this query.
I need to UPDATE the "hit" and "hit_date" columns when the "amount" value is down (for example) of a 90% of the previous value.

Something like this, in two words (no query)

```
Execute query-->update rows-->check if 'amount' value is down 90%--> if yes --> update hit (set to 1) and update hit_date (CURRENT_DATE()).
```

Is possible to do that via MySQL or I have to write a more complex php script?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If value is down by 90% than hit=1 what if less than 90% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hardly provided any code to go off here, so I'm guessing you are using `mysqli` otherwise please adapt:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT amount FROM " . mysqli_real_escape_string($jackpot->gameId) . " WHERE gameId = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($jackpot->gameId) . "' ORDER BY hit_date DESC LIMIT 1");
$current = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// run the insert here

if((($current['amount'] - $new['amount'])/100) <= 0.9) {
    // UPDATE table SET hit = 1, hit_date = CURRENT_DATE() WHERE gameId = $jackpot->gameId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO games (
  gameId,
  gameName,
  amount,
  currency,
  date,
  hit,
  hit_date
) VALUES (
  NULL,
  "test",
  91,
  "€",
  CURRENT_DATE(),
  IF(amount > 90, 1, 0),
  IF(amount > 90, CURRENT_DATE(), NULL)
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 amount = 91,
 hit = IF(amount > 90, 1, 0),
 hit_date = IF(amount > 90, CURRENT_DATE(), NULL)
```

Comment: Forget about the trigger procedure I've mentioned before. I've misunderstood the question a little bit. The answer above will do the work.